# python: beautifulsoup find div contain specific text and ignore <br> tag

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

```
<div class="A">123</div>
<div class="A">456<br>789</div>

soup.find('div', text = lambda text: text and '789' in text, attrs = {'class' : 'A'}, recursive=False)
```

returns nothing.

and,
if the <br> is replaced with "" in browser.page.source generated by selenium, then soup it, it works.

but,if the <br> is replaced with "" in soup generated by beautifulsoup, it doesn't work.

Though in the modified soup the <br> is removed, but the "find" function still seeks in the unmodified soup.

Comment: So you are looking for a div with class A and containing text 789? To return what?

Answer (score 1):

Use a list comprehension:

```
print([x for x in soup.find_all('div',class_='A') if '789' in x.text])
```